# Set proper conditional statement in WHILE LOOP

Tags: php, while-loop, conditional-statements

**After submitting a mysqli_query to select open/unfulfilled orders from a cart database the results is output to the screen with a standard WHILE LOOP.**

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($oresult)) { include('orders-open.php');}
```

**orders-open.php is simply the internal part of a TABLE:**

```
 <tr style="color:#FFF;">
    <td><?php echo $row['Buyer']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Cart_Date']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Item_Number']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Item_Title']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Item_FPrice']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Item_Qty']; ?></td>
    </tr>
```

**So here is my question, I want to apply a simple HTML "`<HR>`" tag between the records at the point where the value in $row['Buyer'] changes, so by example:**

```
John Doe    9/11/13       123456     Item 1       $5.99     5
John Doe    9/11/13       123654     Item 2       $8.99     3
John Doe    9/9/13        321456     Item 3       $4.99     2

(HR - Horizontal Rule Tag here)

Mike Doe    9/7/13       123555     Item 1       $9.99     2
Mike Doe    9/7/13       123777     Item 2       $2.99     6
```

**What would be the best way to write the conditional statement inside the WHILE LOOP to compare the $row[Buyer'] result to the previous $row['Buyer'] result?**

Comment: Just save `$row['Buyer']` value in first loop and compare it with next values (refreshing when value changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$first_run = TRUE;
$previous_buyer = NULL;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($oresult)) { 
      if($first_run) {
         $first_run = FALSE;
         $previous_buyer = $row['Buyer'];
      }
   include('orders-open.php');
}
```

And then in your include file:

```
<?php if($previous_buyer != $row['Buyer']) { 
    echo '<HR width="100%">'; 
    $previous_buyer = $row['Buyer'];
} ?>
<tr style="color:#FFF;">
    <td><?php echo $row['Buyer']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Cart_Date']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Item_Number']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Item_Title']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Item_FPrice']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Item_Qty']; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It occurs to me after the fact that you are inside a table.  I'm not sure how well <HR> will render between Table Rows.  You might want to replace echo '<HR width="100%">'; with <TR><TD colspan=6><HR width="100%"></TD></TR>

Comment: Thank you, this did work but the HR tag did not render as you mentioned (Actually it did... but it rendered at top of table and not between records) -  After the change mentioned in your comment it all rendered properly, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
$buyer = null ;  //Cache buyer in a variable, because $row is reset in the loop.

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($oresult)) {
   include('orders-open.php');
   if ($buyer !== $row["Buyer"]){
     echo ($buyer !== null) ? "<hr/>" : "" ;
     $buyer = $row["Buyer"] ;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$prev_buyer = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($oresult))
{
  if($prev_buyer !== $row['Buyer'])
  {
    //Do Something
  }

  include('orders-open.php');

  $prev_buyer = $row['Buyer']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as Elon said above - change this:

`while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($oresult)) { include('orders-open.php');}`

to

```
$old_buyer = null;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($oresult)) {
    if ($row['Buyer'] != $old_buyer) {
        echo '<hr>';
    }
    $old_buyer = $row['Buyer'];
    include('orders-open.php');
}
```

Comment: The `$old_buyer` variable declaration needs to happen inside the `if` block for it to work.

Comment: $old_buyer will be assigned on every iteration instead of just in case it's different but it will still work this way.

Comment: Hmm, ok, it will work. But it's not necessary to update the variable if it's not different.

Comment: Agreed :) Refactoring makes perfect.

Comment: -1 This code will display a horizontal rule on the first row.